# Getting values to pass in Payfast

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I'm trying to intergrate Payfast with my laravel project. The problem I'm having is that the data isn't being passed to Payfast so Payfast keeps giving me an error saying `The supplied variables are not according to specification:`

Here is my code in my controller

```
public function payPayfast(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'merchant_id' => $request->merchant_id,
        'merchant_key' => $request->merchant_key,
        'return_url' => $request->return_url,
        'cancel_url' => $request->cancel_url,
        'm_payment_id' => $request->m_payment_id,
        'amount' => $request->amount,
        'item_name' => 'Test Item From Controller',
        'item_description' => 'This is a test product',
        'email_confirmation' => '1',
        'confirmation_address' => '',
        'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        'signature' => $request->signature,
    ];

    return redirect()->to('https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process')->with('data', $data);
}
```

here is my code in my confirmation.blade.php

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <h1>Order Confrimation</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form action="{{ route('payfast.payPayfast') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="11111111">
                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="2222222222222">
                <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{{ route('payfast.success') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{ route('payfast.cancel') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{ route('payfast.notify') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value="01AB">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="completePrice" value="{{ $total }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="A test product">
                <input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="confirmation_address" value="test@test.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="eft">

                <?php
                    $success = url('payfast-success');
                    $cancel = url('payfast-cancel');
                    $notify = url('payfast-notify');
                    $original_str = getAscii('merchant_id=11111111&merchant_key=2222222222222&return_url='.$success.'&cancel_url='.$cancel.'&notify_url='.$notify.'&m_payment_id=01AB&amount='.$totalPrice.'&item_name=Test Item&item_description=A test product&email_confirmation=1&confirmation_address=test@test.com&payment_method=eft');
                    $hash_str = hash('MD5', $original_str);
                    $hash = strtolower($hash_str);
                ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{ $hash }}">

                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit"><img src="{{ asset('img/eft-payfast.jpg') }}"></button>
            </form>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to send it to your own controler first in order to perform additional checks on the data before redirecting to PayFast? If not, then you can just post directly to PayFast from your form - this is how most PayFast integrations are done, via a `form post`.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` function adds the data to the session, but PayFast expects the data to be in the url, e.g. `https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process?amount=100&merchant_id=12&merchant_key=23&item_name=cool`.

It doesn't seem like the [URLGenerator](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html) provides an easy way to turn an array into query parameters. You could simply construct the query using string concatenation or have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481793/3486675) which includes a function to construct such a path.